# Broken images in simple HTML dom

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, simple-html-dom

I am using simple_html_dom.php library to fetch required elements from page like www.lifehacker.com but when i fetch images some images don't appers and their links looks broken. This is the code that i am using

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
$("p").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("h1").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("img").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("href").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    br{
        display: none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0 auto;max-width:900px; border:1px solid; padding:20px; margin-top:20px; ">



<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.lifehacker.com/');

foreach($html->find('.icon') as $item) {
$item->outertext = '';
}
$html->save();
foreach($html->find('br') as $item) {
$item->outertext = '';
}
$html->save();
$title = $html->find('title',0)->innertext;
$title = '<h1>'.$title.'<h1>';
echo $title;



$html=$html->find('h1 , h2 , h3  ,img, p');

foreach($html as $elements){
foreach($elements->find('a') as $element) {
if (isset($element->href)) {
    $element->href = null;
}

}
foreach($elements->find('br') as $element){
    if(isset($element->br)){
        $element->br=null;
    }
}
echo $elements.'<br>';
}
?>


</body>
</html>
```

This is the images of broken urls 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLEac.jpg)

Comment: are they relative url's ? If so you would need to turn them into absolute ones

Comment: how is this possible.?

Comment: check if protocol and domain are in image url string, if not add them to string

Comment: just give some hint about that how can i add url?

Comment: use string comparison methods in your php to check the url values